# Array to string conversion error php sql

Tags: php, html, sql, arrays

The array get from this form (Select Boxes).

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php require("Connections/Project.php"); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<?php
        $sql_s="SELECT * FROM t_dvd_copy";
        $query_s=mysql_query($sql_s);
 ?>
<body>
  <?php
        $sql="SELECT *, dvd_title FROM t_dvd_copy INNER JOIN t_dvd ORDER BY dvd_title ASC";
        $query=mysql_query($sql);

        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

?>
<form action="calculatepage.php" method="post">
<table width="200" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['dvd_title']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['price']?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['dvd_copy_id']?>" name="checkbox[]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>

  <?php
        }
    ?>
      <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I want to use the array that got from form to show it in sql table where the ID(s) is from the form/array (calculatepage.php)

```
<?php include("Connections/Project.php");?>
<?php session_start();?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Calculate</title>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
$ide=$_POST['checkbox'];

$sql="select * from t_dvd_copy where dvd_copy_id='$ide'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row['dvd_copy_id'];
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I got error message "Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\pro\calculatepage.php on line 17"

I tested it first with foreach and print_r. It does shows the numeric values.

How do i fix this?

Comment: `$ide` is an array, and you cannot simply interpolate it into a string.

Comment: Your checkbox variable passed from your form is an array; you can't insert that willy-nilly into an SQL statement

Comment: Can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You can't include an array into a string. So,

```
$sql = "select * from t_dvd_copy where dvd_copy_id = '$ide' ";
```

is impossible, and will throw you an error.

Instead, you'll probably have to inspect your `$ide` array to see what's inside, and use the right element. Maybe use [implode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and change the condition to `IN` instead of `=` :

```
$sql = "select * from t_dvd_copy where dvd_copy_id IN (" . implode(',', $ide) . ") ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The Select query is wrongly written.If the checkbox input is having an array of ids then the conditional operator in the select query will be 'IN' rather than '='.